# Current Context for Iron-Router in Templates

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

So I've got iron-router that returns `Posts.find({_id: id})` in it's data function.

Now I'm wondering how I should handle this in the respective template.

My Question: What is the data context for Iron-Router?

In my template I would be doing something like this

```
{{#each some_context}}
{{content}} <br>
{{/each}}
```

So what would be the context I should be going with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data function in iron-router do something like this

```
        var return_object = {
            all_posts: Posts.find({_id: id})
        }

        return return_object;
```

In your html file you can do something like this

```
<template name="all_posts">
    {{#each all_posts}}
        {{title}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The router sets the data context to whatever you return in the `data function`. In this case you've returned `return_object` so you have access to all of it's fields. Structuring your return like this ensures that you can use the right `data context` when going through your each.